# Reason of enclosing parenthesis for type cast

Tags: java, object, methods, type-conversion

```
if (obj instanceof String) {
    return (String) obj;
} else {
    return ((BlogPost) obj).getTitle();
```

Why does the line that returns the tite of `BlogPost` need parenthesis to be wrapped around the reference `obj` and `BlogPost`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the reference of `obj` is of a different type than `BlogPost`, the statement `((BlogPost) obj)` does cast `obj` to the type `BlogPost`. Without the parenthesises the statement:

```
(BlogPost) obj.getTitle();
```

would mean: cast the return value of `getTitle()` to `BlogPost`. While with parentesises the statement:

```
((BlogPost) obj).getTitle();
```

means: cast `obj` to the type `BlogPost` and than call the method `getTitle()` on the instance of type `BlogPost`.

Answer (score 1):

This will cast `obj` as a `BlogPost` and execute `getTitle` under this context.

```
return ((BlogPost) obj).getTitle();
```

Whereas this would execute `getTitle` for `obj` (which probably isn´t defined for this class) and would cast the result as `BlogPost` (which wouldn´t work for `String -> BlogPost`)

```
return (BlogPost) obj.getTitle();
```

In the end this is a deciding factor in which order the code gets executed in order to let `obj` the correct context it has to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is called type casting in Java. See the section Casting Objects in this Oracle's Java documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

((BlogPost) obj).getTitle(); 
will cast the object to the blogpost type and then call the getTitle() method.
If it was written as (BlogPost) obj.getTitle();, it would get the return value from the getTitle() method and then cast it to the type of BlogPost().